# Is this immutable object threadsafe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, immutability, atomic

I have a class which loads some data from a server and transforms it. The class contains a method that reloads this data from the server.

I'm not sure if the reload is threadsafe, but I read that i might need to add a volatile keyword or using locks.

```cs
    public class Tenants : ITenants
    {
        private readonly string url = "someurl";
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

        private ConfigParser parser;

        public Tenants(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        public async Task Refresh()
        {
            TConfig data = await ConfigLoader.GetData(httpClientFactory.CreateClient(), url);
            parser = new ConfigParser(data);
        }

        public async Task<TConfig> GetSettings(string name)
        {
            if (parser == null)
                await Refresh();

            return parser.GetSettings(name);

        }
    }

    public class ConfigParser
    {

        private readonly ImmutableDictionary<string, TConfig> configs;

        public ConfigParser(TConfig[] configs)
        {

            this.configs = configs.ToImmutableDictionary(s => s.name, v => v);
        }


        public TConfig GetSettings(string name)
        {
            if (!configs.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return configs[name];
        }

    }
```

The Tenants class will be injected as a singleton intoother classes via DI IOC.

I think that this design makes this threadsafe.
It is fully atomic, and immutable with no exposed members to be changed by any consuming code. (TConfig is also immutable)

I also dont think i need a lock, if 2 threads try to set the reference at the same time, last one wins, which i am happy with.

And i dont know enough to understand if i need volatile. But from what i understood about it, i wont need it, as there is only 1 reference if parser that i care about, and its never exposed outside this class.

But i think some of my statements/assumptions above could be wrong.

Comment: Your `Tenants` class is **not** immutable.

Comment: How so? I only change the parser internaly as a new reference and there are no setters.

Comment: Every time you call `Refresh`, it mutates.

Comment: Immutable objects are objects which once loaded cannot be modified by **any** way: external or internal.

Comment: Ok understood, Tenants isnt immutable. But I think its threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

From your comments I can deduce that you do not understand the difference between immutable and thread safety.

Immutability means an instance of an object can not be mutated (it's internal or external state can not change).

Thread safe means multiple threads can access the class/method without causing errors like race conditions, deadlocks or unexpected behavior like something which has to be executed only once is executed twice.

Immutable objects are thread safe, but something doesn't have to be immutable to be thread safe.

Your `Tenants` class is neither immutable nor thread safe because:

1. It's internal sate can change after instantiation.
2. It contains unexpected behavior where the request to receive the config is executed twice, where it should only happen once.

If you read my answer below you can determine that if you are ok with the request happening twice (which you shouldn't be): You don't have to do anything, but you could add the volatile keyword to the `parser` field to prevent **SOME** scenarios, but definitely not all.

You don't see any locks in immutable objects because there's no writing happening to the state of the object.

When there are writing operations in an object it is not immutable anymore (like your `Tenants` class). To make an object like that thread safe, you need to lock the write operations that can cause errors like the unexpected behavior of something which has to be executed only once is executed twice.

---

`ConfigParser` Seems to be thread safe, `Tenants` however definitely isn't.

Your `Tenants` class is also not immutable, since it exposes a method which changes the state of the class (both the `GetSettings` and `Refresh` methods).

If 2 threads call `GetSettings` at the same time when `parser` is `null`, 2 requests will be made to receive the `ConfigParser`. You can be OK with this, but it is bad practice, and also means the method is not thread safe.

If you are fine with the request being executed twice you could use [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) here:

> The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by multiple threads that are executing at the same time. The compiler, the runtime system, and even hardware may rearrange reads and writes to memory locations for performance reasons. Fields that are declared volatile are not subject to these optimizations. Adding the volatile modifier ensures that all threads will observe volatile writes performed by any other thread in the order in which they were performed.

Volatile will prevent threads from having outdated values. This means you could prevent *some* of the extra requests happening (from the threads which still think `parser` is null), but it will not completely prevent an method or instruction from being executed multiple times at the same time.

In this situation you need to [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement):

> The lock statement acquires the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executes a statement block, and then releases the lock. While a lock is held, the thread that holds the lock can again acquire and release the lock. Any other thread is blocked from acquiring the lock and waits until the lock is released.

Meaning you can prevent multiple threads from executing an method or instruction multiple times at the same time.

Unfortunately, you can't use `await` inside a `lock`.

What you want to do is:

- If `Refresh` needs to be called:

  - If another thread is already working on the `Refresh`

    - Wait for the other thread to finish, and do not call `Refresh`
    - Continue with the result from the other thread
  - if no other thread is already working on the `Refresh`

    - Invoke the `Refresh` method

I have written a library for this called [TaskSynchronizer](https://github.com/JoasE/TaskSynchronizer). You can use that to accomplish a true thread safe version of you `Tenants` class.

Example:

```cs
public static TaskSynchronizer Synchronizer = new TaskSynchronizer();

public static async Task DoWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(100); // Some heavy work.
    Console.WriteLine("Work done!");
}

public static async Task WorkRequested()
{
    using (Synchronizer.Acquire(DoWork, out var task)) // Synchronize the call to work.
    {
        await task;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(WorkRequested());
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

will output:

```
Work done!
```

EG: The async `DoWork` method has only be invoked once, even tho it has been invoked twice at the same time.

Comment: Here you are talking about fixing the bad practice part so i only request this once. This is something that needs to be fixed. However im more concerned on keeping the code from crashing

Comment: Please read the entire answer, it provides all the information you need to come to the solution to your problem. If you have any more questions I am happy to help. @crazymalteser

Comment: I asked here so someone can give me a solution. I can add volatile and i can add a lock. I can understand what those 2 will do.
But that doesn't mean its the correct solution. When i look at immutable collections of .netcore, they dont use any volatiles or locks. I am trying to do something similar

Comment: @crazymalteser I have added an explanation of immutable vs thread safe, since you don't seem to understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. So essentially, it is not thread safe just because there is unexpected behavior (such as what you mentioned (getting data twice)).

Comment: Re, "To make an object like that thread safe, you need to lock the write operations." A common newbie mistake is to think that it's _enough_ to lock the write operations. "Thread safety" is a property of data, not code. Shared data is thread safe if no thread can ever see it in an invalid/inconsistent/broken state that was caused by the action of some other thread. In order to provide that guarantee, it often is important to lock the data even in a thread that only wants to _look_ at it.